# ConvertFrom-String returns symbol not text

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Performing the following code with student text name Infinity returns the infinity symbol and not the actual text. Can anyone explain why this is the case and what can be done to rectify.

```
$person="Infinity,One"
$personsplit=$person | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "," -PropertyNames firstname,surname
```

`$personsplit` returns the following output

the first name is now a symbol and not text data?

Expected to see the output as

```
first name surname
--------- -------
 Infinity One
```

However, it returns the following

```
firstname surname  
--------- -------   
     ∞    One
```

For anyone interested Im currently running the following version of powershell

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $psversiontable

Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.503                                   
PSEdition                      Desktop                                         
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.503                                  
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                 
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                             
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                             
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: the parsing system in that cmdlet sees `Infinity` as a math term and sets the property type to `float`. my setup gives `Infinity` as a _floating point text name_, not as the infinity symbol. you can do one of at least two things ... provide a template that sets the `[string]` type for that property OR use `ConvertFrom-CSV` and give the cmdlet a `-Header` line instead of a `-PropertyNames` line.

Comment: Can you run `$PSVersionTable` and add it to your question? I wasn't able to reproduce it (PS 5.1).

Comment: @robdy - take a REALLY close look at the output you get. the `Infinity` word it _right_ justified while the `One` word it _left_ justified. that is numerical layout on the 1st and text layout on the 2nd. plus, if you run `.GetType()` on each property , the 1st will be `float` ... really strange glitch ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you're absoutely right, thanks for that!

Comment: @robdy - you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'd like to note that word 'template' in the name of parameters is misleading since it's more like a sample than a template.

Comment: @montonero - the help for that cmdlet uses `template` and the parameter for using a template is `-TemplateContent` ... so i think `template` is appropriate in this situation. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes, that's true, but when you start to look to it closely it's not that kind of template people have used to. I don't argue with you, just a note.

Comment: your statement about "template" in this situation makes no sense to me ... but that is ok. [*grin*]

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you've found a bug/quirk in the way that `ConvertFrom-String` attempts to automatically cast the values that it creates, and in your case seems to take the string 'Infinity' and instead cast is as `[single]::PositiveInfinity`.

An alternative safer solution would be to not use `ConvertFrom-String` and do something like this instead:

```
$person="Infinity,One"
$personsplit = $person -split ','

[pscustomobject]@{
    firstname = $personsplit[0]
    lastname = $personsplit[1]
}
```

If you don't mind them being in separate variables you could also do this:

```
$firstname,$lastname = $person -split ','
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, appreciate the answer and quick reply. I'll incorporate your solutiuon as a current workaround. Is there anyway to escalate this to Microsoft; believe it or not Infinity is a students name in our database.

Comment: I don't think you're likely going to get a fix in Windows PowerShell. Looks like with PowerShell Core the `ConvertFrom-String` cmdlet is not available and not yet likely to be ported as it uses code that is not open source: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2123

Comment: See this comment specifically: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2123#issuecomment-328728812