# How can i replace data in multiple .txt files at once in Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, msdn

I have multiple .txt files in a folder, which have a specific data format in which every line, starts from 3 digit numbers, example say.

```
101,3333,35899,BufferC1,99,02,333
102,3344,30079,BufferD2,89,03,444
.... and so on.
```

Now, if the record starts with "101", then I have to replace the 3rd & 5th index element of the same line with some text. Once all files are replaced, then I have to copy all modified files to another directory/folder on the same machine.

I have written some code which is not working. Please help me as I am a newbie in powershell. Am I working on a correct approach?

```
 $FileNamesList = @(Get-ChildItem C:\TestFiles\*.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
    
     for($i=0; $i -lt $FileNamesList.count; $i++)
        {      
            # original folder path
            $FilePath1 = 'C:\TestFiles\' + $FileNamesList[$i]
            
            #modified files after text is replaced will be copied in another folder
            $FilePath2 = 'C:\TestFilesModified\' + $FileNamesList[$i]   
    
            $OriginalFileData = Get-Content $FilePath1
    
        # Is this correct, can i assign foreach cmd result to a variable?
        $ModifiedFileData= ForEach($Row in $OriginalFileData ) 
                    {                 
                         If($Row.Split(",")[0] -eq "101") 
                         {
                            $Row -replace($Row.Split(",")[3]),"Test File"
                            $Row -replace($Row.Split(",")[5]),"Test Data"
                         } 

                     else{
                       $Row
                        }

             Out-File -FilePath $FilePath2 -InputObject $ModifiedFileData
            }
```

Comment: Do all the files have the same number of columns? Do they have a header row, or only the data?

Comment: @ Mathias R. Jessen, these are just plain .txt files and have no header, only have data. Also, the files dont have same number of columns. I just need to change lines that start with "101' in the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a shame those files don't have headers which would make them proper Csv files and so much more reliable to work with..

What you can do now is to loop over these files line-by line and split on the delimiter character `,`.

**Edit**

The code now uses a regex to split each string on the comma, UNLESS this comma is inside a quoted field.

```
# create a regex string to split on the delimiter character ',' unless it isinside quotes
$commaUnlessQuoted = ',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test'-Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.FullName
    $data = switch -Regex -File $file {
        '^101,' {
            # first field is '101', replace element index 3 with "Test File" and element index 5 with "Test Data"
            $fields = $_ -split $commaUnlessQuoted
            $fields[3] = "Test File"
            $fields[5] = "Test Data"
            # rejoin the fields with a comma
            $fields -join ','
        }
        '^002,' {
            # first field is '002', replace element index 3 with the current date
            $fields = $_ -split $commaUnlessQuoted
            $fields[3] = (Get-Date).ToLongDateString()
            $fields -join ','
        }
        # you can add as many regex conditions here as you like.
        # default means no conditions above matched, so return te line as-is
        default {$_}
    }
    $data | Set-Content -Path $file -Force
    # copy the modified file to somewhere else
    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination 'C:\TestFilesModified'
}
```

Regex details for `$commaUnlessQuoted`:

```
,               Match the character “,” literally
(?=             Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   (?:          Match the regular expression below
      [^"]      Match any character that is NOT a “"”
         *      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      "         Match the character “"” literally
      [^"]      Match any character that is NOT a “"”
         *      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      "         Match the character “"” literally
   )*           Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [^"]         Match any character that is NOT a “"”
      *         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   $            Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
)
```

---

Per your comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66890303/9898643), if you need to also throw non-terminating exceptions, just change these lines:

```
$data | Set-Content -Path $file -Force
# copy the modified file to somewhere else
Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination 'C:\TestFilesModified'
```

into

```
try {
    $data | Set-Content -Path $file -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    # copy the modified file to somewhere else
    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination 'C:\TestFilesModified' -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch { throw }  # just rethrow the exception so it 'bubbles up' to the calling script
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is a very good approach.

Comment: @nick235 It is also the fastest approach and.. `ConvertFrom-String` also has its bugs as you can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56423113/9898643)

Comment: @nick235 I have edited the `-split` to use a regex that will ensure the code does not split on commas that are inside quoted fields.

Comment: 1. What if i need to replace data in some other line, like if first element is ^002, then i want $_.P4 = Get-Date. Can i use Elseif in the code?
2. If one of the line has null element, then will the script fail , ex; 002,3333,4444,Test2,ccd3,,,,,210215. There are null elements and i still want to update P4.
3. If i have multiple records ex, 2000 lines start with "01", then how can i achieve that?

Comment: Sorry to bother you with so many questions, but i have very less experince in coding in general. It would be great if you can clear some doubts. Thanks a lot for your help. Your code worked very fast and modified many files in seconds :)

Comment: now what is happening is that after switch Case 2, i,e lines that  start with "^002' are modified, in the modified files, that line itself has been deleted. I added $fields -join ',' but no success.

Comment: Hi @Theo, its still not fixed. :( The row starting with 002 is still not  visible .

Comment: your answer is the best ;0

Comment: Hi Theo, can you please explain the Regex string in detail. I cant understand it clearly: $commaUnlessQuoted = ',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)'  . It will be very helpful.

Comment: @nick235 I have already added the regex details for it, but what it does is it makes a split on every comma, unless this comma is inside quotes, because then it is part of a field and the string should only be split on commas that separate the fields.

Comment: I want  to check that if the txt file doesn't have rows starting with "01" or "02", then it should throw an error or a message.   $file = $_.FullName
    $FileData = Get-Content $file

    if($FileData -notcontains "01,"){
    Write-Host $file "File is INVALID"

    }  ... but its not working. Can you please help. Thanks.

Comment: @nick235 Please post a new question for this, as it is not directly related to this one. There are multiple solutions to what you now ask, however not by using `-notcontains`. Think regex, where you can anchor to the beginning of each line with `'^0[12]'`, or by using `-notlike`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will implement these solutions and post a new question, just incase i encounter any issues.

Comment: posted a new Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890303/how-to-verify-if-a-string-is-not-present-in-a-txt-file-in-powershell

Answer (score 1):

I like [@Theo's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66199598/4749264). I starting thinking along the same lines and writing similarly minded code.  However, I got hung up on the CSV idea and ended up with a few alternate approaches to share.

There are a few of issues with a CSV approach:

1. Lack of headers
2. Difficulty re-exporting because `Export-Csv` doesn't have a `-NoHeader` parameter
3. Dealing with a variable number of columns as mentioned in the comments

My first approach to this was to use the `ConvertFrom-String` cmdlet to get formal objects out of the raw data.

```
$SourceFolder      = "C:\Temp\SourceFolder"
$DestinationFolder = "C:\Temp\destination"

ForEach( $File in Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder -Filter *.txt )
{
    $DestinationFile = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $File.Name
    
    $File | 
    Get-Content | 
    ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "," | 
    ForEach-Object{
        If( $_.P1 -eq 101 ) {
            $_.P3 = "P3 Replacement Value"
            $_.P5 = "P5 Replacement Value"
        }
        $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -join "," # Output from the loop
    } |
    Set-Content -Path $DestinationFile
}
```

The advantage of this is you don't need to know how many fields there are in any 1 file or even any 1 row of a given file.  `ConvertFrom-String` will simply add extra properties for a given row.  Unrolling the values with `$_.PSObject.Properties.Value` also allows for an arbitrary number of properties with limited code.

The Second approach requires knowing the maximum number of columns.  For the purposes of the example, assume we have a variable number of columns, but never more than say 8.  We can use the `-Header` argument with the `Import-Csv` command.

```
$Header            = "P1","P2","P3","P4","P5","P6","P7","P8"
$SourceFolder      = "C:\Temp\SourceFolder"
$DestinationFolder = "C:\Temp\destination"

ForEach( $File in Get-ChildItem C:\temp\SourceFolder -filter *.txt )
{
    $DestinationFile = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $File.Name
    
    Import-Csv -Path $File.FullName -Header $Header |
    ForEach-Object{
        If( $_.P1 -eq 101 ) {
            $_.P3 = "P3 Replacement Value"
            $_.P5 = "P5 Replacement Value"
        }
        ($_.PSObject.Properties.Value -join ",").TrimEnd(",") # Output from the loop
    } |
    Set-Content -Path $DestinationFile
}
```

Note: I supposed even if you didn't know the maximum number of fields you could assign big array to the `$Header` variable.

Note: The `.TrimEnd(",")` method. Since there may be fewer fields on agiven line than there are elements in the `$Header` array, `Import-Csv` wil add a property and assign it a null value.  In turn this may result in extra commas in the string resulting from the `-join`.

WARNING: This may also pose a problem if there are legitimately null trailing fields.

Finally, I did figure out a way to leverage the `*-Csv` cmdlets a little further, but it only works with the `ConvertFrom-String` example:

```
$SourceFolder      = "C:\Temp\SourceFolder"
$DestinationFolder = "C:\Temp\destination"

ForEach( $File in Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder -Filter *.txt )
{
    $DestinationFile = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $File.Name
    
    $File | 
    Get-Content | 
    ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "," | 
    ForEach-Object{
        If( $_.P1 -eq 101 ) {
            $_.P3 = "P3 Replacement Value"
            $_.P5 = "P5 Replacement Value"
        }
        $_
    } |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Set-Content -Path $DestinationFile
}
```

This doesn't need a `-join` expression, however it's at the expense of the additional `Select-Object` pipeline.

Comment: thanks for a very detailed answer. What is P1, P3, P5 in the code. The approach i was using was to convert Get-Content in Array and then reference the elements by Index $Array[0], $Array[3] ... etc?

Comment: Also, in the Output folder, the new file content keeps on getting appended again and again to the same file. If I want to run the script and want the files to be same but whole file content should be modified fully everytime with the latest script run content, as i will display Get-Date everytime in the files, is it possible?

Comment: Hi Steven, there is one issue that i am facing. Now, in the modified files, the starting 0 is getting truncated. Like the line starts from 023,3333,4444,Test3....an so on,then in the modified file i see: 23,3333,4444,Test3

Comment: P1...P3...P5 are generic props generated by `ConvertFrom-String` cmdlet.  In the `*-csv` example the P's are because of the header names I gave it.  You can change those to better represent your data.  Once it's converted to an object we refer to the property names instead of array elements.

Comment: The truncation of 0 is probably due to type conversion and or the typing that Results from `Convert-FromString` .  That's a serious shortcoming, but I'll see if there's an easy fix.  The csv example doesn't appear to have that issue. I'm not having the append issue, we used `Set-Content` not `Add-Content`. not sure what may be causing it on your side.

Comment: Ok thanks , i will rename properties to represent my data. Yes, 0 trucation should not happen with ConvertFrom-String cmdlet.

Comment: The csv example doesn’t truncate. However, there are potential issues there as well. They are already noted in the answer. Please note: while this is interesting thought exercise, @theo ‘s answer is perfectly valid and more expedient in the sense you don’t have to look for caveats in pre-existing cmdlets. You should probably pursue those samples or som hybrid along with accepting that answer.