# How to verify if a string is not present in a .txt file in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, shell, automation, powershell-4.0

I have 10 .txt files and all these files have rows or records that start with 2-digit numbers like 01, 02, 03, 04 ... and so on.

```
File1.txt

01,333,abc,test2,44,55
02,883,def,test5,33,093
03....and so on.
```

1. Now, if powershell finds a file that doesn't contain a record that starts with either "01" or "02", then i want to throw an error or exception.
2. Also, if there is such kind of file, then i don't want to copy that invalid format file to the output folder. I only want to modify and copy txt files that have 01 or 02.

How can i do this?

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\InputFiles\'-Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object { 
        $file = $_.FullName
        $FileData = Get-Content $file
    
        if($FileData[01] -notlike "01,"){
        Write-Host $file "File is INVALID"
    
        }

 $data = switch -Regex -File $file {
        '^01,' {
             do stuff...

        }

        '^02,' {
            
           do stuff...
        }
        
        default {$_}
    } 
   
    }

  $data | Set-Content -Path $file -Force 
        Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination 'C:\OutputFiles\' -Force
```

Comment: "a file that doesn't contain a record that starts with either `01` or `02`" - so a file where the first line/record starts with `02,` is okay?

Comment: Your .txt file sounds like a .CSV file...

Comment: @Mathias, if both 01 and 02 are not present, then it will be a perfect case of invalid file.

Comment: @T-Me, it is a .txt file.

Comment: @nick235 However if it's content follows the rules of a [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Specification) you can  just treat it like one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this could be

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\InputFiles\'-Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object { 
    $isValid = $true
    switch -Regex -File $_.FullName {
        '^0[12],' { <# line begins with '01' or '02', so it's OK; do nothing #> }
        default   { $isValid = $false; break } 
    }
    if ($isValid) {
        # modify the file where you need and copy to the destination folder 
    }
    else {
        Write-Error "File $($_.FullName) is INVALID"
    }
}
```

or do it without using regex:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\InputFiles\'-Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object { 
    $isValid = $true
    foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName)) {
        if ($line -notlike '01,*' -and $line -notlike '02,*') {
            $isValid = $false 
            break
        }
    }   
    if ($isValid) {
        # modify the file where you need and copy to the destination folder 
    }
    else {
        Write-Error "File $($_.FullName) is INVALID"
    }
}
```

Comment: @nick235 If the reply helps you, you could accept it as an answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread
[how_does_accepting_an_answer_work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Hi Theo, this works fine, but there is another issue. If any one of the file or files are  not modified due to any reason, then how can we throw an exception?

Comment: @nick235 If by modify you mean something like in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66198617/how-can-i-replace-data-in-multiple-txt-files-at-once-in-powershell), then the `Set-Content` and/or `Copy-Item` cmdlets there should throw terminating exceptions. If you want to force also non-terminating exceptions to be thrown, wrap that in a `try {..Set-Content..} catch{ trhow }` block and add `-ErrorAction Stop` to both cmdlets.